# How to remove answers from analysis based on another answer in SPSS

Tags: spss

In my study, I asked people to make choices between pairs of activities. In another question, I also asked them how likely they would be to do these activities (e.g. they were asked how likely they'd be to go swimming; they were also asked to choose between going swimming and going for a walk).

I want to REMOVE from my analysis all answers to pairs that include an activity a person said they'd do "Under no circumstances".

I have already created a variable for each activity that takes 1 if a person answered "Under no circumstances" and take 0 if they chose any other answer (likelihood of doing X). I'm not sure how to proceed now. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

do if x=1.

*type the correct condition in the line above.

recode y (else=sysmis).

*recoding all valid cases to sysmis in the target variable.

end if.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a person said that he under no circumstances will swim and the person has chosen to swim over to skate. That would be a contradiction and you would like to eliminate these contradictions from your analysis.

However, note that these contradictions can be errors of the person questioned (which logic dictates), but could also indicate something else, like "I have to choose 'under no circumstance"s', but ....". It might be worth while to investigate.

Having said that, I would flag these records and make a selection.
In code that could look something like this:

```
NUMERIC Flag (F1.0).
COMPUTE Flag = 0.
DO IF (UnderNoCircumstances = "Swimming" and PairwiseComparisonPreference = "Swimming").
+ COMPUTE Flag = 1.
END IF.
EXECUTE.
FREQUENCIES Flag.

* Delete the contradictionary records permanently.
SELECT IF (Flag = 0).
EXECUTE.

* From here on your analysis on non-contradictionary records.
...
```